# Launch Failure as no Binaries Could Be Found

Tags: c++, avr

I am using AVR32 studio 2.6 to try to compile a c++ project, but everytime i try to run it, it says launch failure as no binaries could be found. Is there a fix for this error code ?

Comment: Duplicated question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158677/encountering-launch-failed-as-no-binaries-could-be-found

Answer (score 0):

I have never used AVR32, but this is a very common C++ error. It essentially means that it can't find the executable to run the program from. Which either means you have not built the project properly, or your makefile has errors.

Make sure your project is properly built first, and if that isn't the problem, look up how to create makefiles for the compiler you are using.