# Encountering "Launch failed as no binaries could be found"

Tags: avr, avr-gcc

In AVR32 Studio (2.6) I'm trying to debug an AVR project and I get the error message "Launch failed as no binaries could be found".

I can see in the console that Build is complete (an executable .elf file is in the build folder) and I've cleaned my project, created a new build configuration and I still can't seem to launch (and or program the chip) the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your *debug launch configuration*. It ought to be a little more intuitive, but is not. After you create and build your project, there is no valid debug launch configuration and you need to create one.

You need to go thru project options -> debug configurations -> avr32 application -> double click to create one.

Please read [Debugging in AVR32 Studio](https://www.kth.se/social/upload/56/Debugging%2520in%2520AVR32%2520Studio%2520combined%2520pfd.pdf) and [AVR32015: AVR32 Studio getting started](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc32086.pdf)
 for more details.

Comment: Ah, I see I was creating a debug launch configuration but something must have messed up. I've tried again it seems to work.